# Excessive stack depth comparing types 'Snapshot<T>' and 'DataSnapshot'. [2321]

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to define type-safe versions of some Firebase database constructs, starting with snapshots, so I wrote:

```
interface Snapshot<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
  val(): T;
}
```

So far so good. Now, I want to define the `child` method, which returns a snapshot of a node's child, in type-safe fashion, so:

```
interface Snapshot<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
  val(): T;
  child<U extends keyof T>(path: U): Snapshot<T[U]>;
}
```

In other words, the parameter to `child` is a string which is a property on `T`, and it returns a snapshot of that property's type. However, this gives me the error:

> Excessive stack depth comparing types 'Snapshot' and 'DataSnapshot'. [2321]

What is the problem, and how can I write this?

Comment: This bug has been fixed. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14825.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the return type of the `child` method in the `firebase.database.DataSnapshot` is that of its enclosing interface. And that does not appear to play nice with your typesafe interface declaration.

The following is a minimal reproduction of the problem:

```ts
interface DataSnapshot {
  child(path: string): DataSnapshot;
}

interface Snapshot<T> extends DataSnapshot {
  child<U extends keyof T>(path: U): Snapshot<T[U]>;
}
```

If the return type of `DataSnapshot` is changed, the error is not raised:

```ts
interface DataSnapshot {
  child(path: string): any;
}

interface Snapshot<T> extends DataSnapshot {
  child<U extends keyof T>(path: U): Snapshot<T[U]>;
}
```

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your interface declaration. I would call this a TypeScript bug.

Interestingly, you can work around the bug by shoving another interface between `Snapshot<T>` and `DataSnapshot`:

```ts
interface DataSnapshot {
  child(path: string): DataSnapshot;
}

interface DataSnapshotAsAny extends DataSnapshot {
  child(path: string): any;
}

interface Snapshot<T> extends DataSnapshotAsAny {
  child<U extends keyof T>(path: U): Snapshot<T[U]>;
}
```

Comment: Have raised issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14794.